# OfficeJS API for inserting slides into PowerPoint presentation

Tags: office-js

I want to be able to insert a slide when I press a button using an Office JS add-in. Is this possible with the API?

I can't find any API support in Office JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
There is an API that will do this: [SlideCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.slidecollection?view=powerpoint-js-preview#powerpoint-powerpoint-slidecollection-add-member(1))

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
There is no API that will insert a new slide into a presentation. But that is a great idea. Please go to the following suggestion on Office Developer User Voice and vote for it: [Allow PowerPoint Add-in to Create New Slide](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13294122-allow-powerpoint-add-in-to-create-new-slide)